# Confusion about Ampere circuital law

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

First of all, I want to make clear that I know modified Maxwell-Ampere circuital law. But still restrict your answers to older version of Ampere circuital law. Suppose we have a constant current carrying wire and consider a point just above the wire, where we know a magnetic field exists. Now consider a loop passing through the point such that its plane does not cut the wire. Thus Inet through loop =0 then by Ampere law B should also be 0 but we know that Magnetic field (B) exists. Now my question is where I am wrong in my understanding to account for the above (Please don't consider displacement current as there is no changing electric field at the point)?

Answer (score 2):

Ampere's law says $$\oint\mathbf B\cdot\text d\mathbf l=\mu_0I_\text{enc}=0$$
around the closed loop. It doesn't say $\mathbf B=0$ for all points on the loop. Note that the value of an integral does not uniquely determine the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you consider a current-carrying wire perpendicular to the paper and that you draw a circle on your paper to represent the loop. Then put arrows pointing in the direction of the magnetic field due to the wire, at several points round your loop. Then consider the components of these fields tangental to the loop. Visualise how ⃗.ℓ⃗ varies as you go round the loop. Sometimes it will be positive, sometimes negative. So the integral can be zero, without  being zero anywhere!

Comment: Thanks Philip Wood